# Падает Telegram Bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Есть боты которые висят на сервере, они принимают вебхуки и дают ответы. Проблема в том что каждым ботом пользуются несколько десяток человек, и когда кто-то начинает флудить отправлять по свыше сотни сообщений за минуту бот перестает отвечать другим пользователям когда обрабатывает информацию полученную 'флудильщиком'. Так же бот при каждом запросе обращается к БД и она падает если не ставить задержку, сейчас задержа стоит 0.5с , но все равно иногда падает. Может кто подсказать что делать?

Вопрос 1:
Бот не отвечает другим пока обрабатывает информацию одного человека

Вопрос 2:
Падает БД после частых подключений

Пробовал ставить в потоки, результат тот же. Как вариант можно поставить ограничение на 30 сообщений в минуту от пользователя но если он будет флудить то это не поможет другим пользователям.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поскольку нет деталей, то можно ответить только в общем:

1. Вы рассуждаете правильно: хорошо бы ограничить кол-во сообщений от одного пользователя. Как вариант - можно погуглить по словам rate-limiting, rate limit, request limit, или “ограничение частоты запросов”, “ограничение доступа к API”, “ограничение запросов”
2. один из простых вариантов - это сделать, чтобы ограничение работало ро ip, с которого произошло обращение.
3. Еще один вариант - если это возможно, кешировать ответы на одинаковые запросы. Тогда не надо будет на каждый запрос обращаться к базе, и скорость ответов бота увеличится.
4. также, можно ставить запросы в очередь. И чем больше от пользователя приходит запросов - тем дальше в очереди отодвигать его. ТОгда все "честные" пользователи будут получать ответы быстро, а "флудильщики" - по остаточному принципу